# React native react-native-pell-rich-editor crash on Android navigation to screen

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-pell-rich-editor in my react-native app. When i navigation
screen add from screen Flatlist, app will crash only on Android. "react-native": "0.64.1", "react-native-pell-rich-editor": "^1.8.6",

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7E0Z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uphcs.png)

Comment: You have to add the code where the error occurs so that people can find the cause of the error.

Comment: add details about your code.

Comment: if possible  share `editorInitializedCallback` code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use this
   `<RichEditor androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true} />`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Please note, this is not an official solution, it's a workaround..

Try to wrap your "react-native-pell-rich-editor" component inside a Scrollview.

what I have done and which is working  :

```
        <ScrollView>
            <RichEditor
                disabled={false}
                containerStyle={styles.editor}
                initialContentHTML={html}
                editorStyle={contentStyle}
                ref={RichText}
                style={{width: '100%'}}
                placeholder={'Description'}
                onChange={(text) => handleChange(text)}
            />
       </ScrollView>
```

-> You can also try to update your webview component, but it didn't work for me.

I'm not sure why this is working. Someone do the same thing [here](https://github.com/wxik/react-native-rich-editor/issues/52)

Answer (score 0):

According to [a comment by uer davidwico in a related GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/wxik/react-native-rich-editor/issues/225#issuecomment-1050911042), this can be solved/avoided by passing `androidLayerType="software"` to the underlying webview. Ex.

```
<RichEditor
  androidLayerType="software"
  ...
/>
```